# AuthorizeAttribute does nothing in ASP.NET Core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project, with a simple authentication system based on cookies, and a few roles and policies. DI is handled with Autofac (not internal DI system of ASP.NET Core).

I know my user is correctly loaded with proper roles, and calls to internal methods like `Context.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))` (from views) are working as expected.

However, all my `AuthorizeAttribute` are not working, depending of the content of my Startup whether they seem to do nothing, or I am always redirected to login page (even if the right requirement is fulfilled).

An annotation like

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Administrator,Collaborator")]
```

or a simple

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

placed on an action method seems to do nothing.

I know that order of calls in startup `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` matter a lot, but despite many attempts and a lot of reading of similar questions on SO or somewhere else, I was not able to make it work as expected.

I share below my whole `Startup` file (sorry for that), in hope somebody will be able to point the correct order (or another kind of fix of course), to make it work for my specific case.

Thanks a lot.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 24, 0, 0);
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/RightError";
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(SecurityPolicies.AdministratorOnly, policy => 
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, UserRoles.Administrator));
                options.AddPolicy(SecurityPolicies.AdministratorOrCollaborator, policy => 
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, UserRoles.Administrator, UserRoles.Collaborator));
            });

            services.AddSession(options => options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4));
            services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter()))
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

            services.AddKendo();
        }

        // ConfigureContainer is where you can register things directly
        // with Autofac. This runs after ConfigureServices so the things
        // here will override registrations made in ConfigureServices.
        // Don't build the container; that gets done for you by the factory.
        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new MyFrontModule());
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(ProcessError);
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            var ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
            {
                NumberFormat = { NumberDecimalSeparator = ".", CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "." }
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { ci },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { ci }
            });
        }

        private void ProcessError(IApplicationBuilder appError)
        {
            appError.Run(async context =>
            {
                // Not relevant for my question
            });
        }
    }
```

I also read that Json Serializer may change something, I am using Newtonsoft with DefaultContractResolver (as above), and I am using Telerik UI components.

Thanks a lot for any useful advice !

Comment: Does `[Authorize]` without specifying roles/policies work?

Comment: I reprodcue your problem and change code to `options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;` it works though I do not know why...

Comment: @XingZou I didn't specify but the problem occurs in IIS Express in development environment, not yet tested in production. I have attempted your solution but unfortunately it doesn't change anything. I have also tested SameAsRequest just in case (as it would have been better than None)

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin to be able to open a controller or action without to be logged, I should put above it AllowAnonymous. If I don't specify anything, I need to be authenticated. So I don't know if I am supposed to observe a different behavior between to not specify anything, or to specify Authorize without arguments.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. What do you mean saying attribute not working? You're authenticated, but cannot call method? Or vice versa - anonymous call bypasses `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin Roles or Policies are not enforced. If my logged user is not "Administrator" and he attempts to execute an action with attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] on top of it, the action is executed and the page is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in question, I have never been able to have `Authorize` attribute working as expected, so as my needs in right management were pretty simple, as a workaround I've just implemented a very straightforward FilterAttribute to verify rights based on owned roles.

```
public class RoleRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RoleRequirementAttribute(params string[] claimValues) 
        : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new []{ claimValues.Select(cv => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, cv)) };
    }
}

public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly IEnumerable<Claim> _claims;

    public ClaimRequirementFilter(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        _claims = claims;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasClaim =  context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(owned => _claims.Any(required => owned.Type == required.Type && owned.Value == required.Value));

        if (!hasClaim)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding .AddRoles<IdentityRole  to the identity setting in the startup file.

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```